# what's the purpose of an empty trait in scala

Tags: scala

In Action.scala from play framework, it has the following code, why it defines a trait "Handler" without any method or field, what's the purpose or benefit of defining an empty trait?

```
trait Handler

/**
 * A handler that is able to tag requests. Usually mixed in to other handlers.
 */
trait RequestTaggingHandler extends Handler {
  def tagRequest(request: RequestHeader): RequestHeader
}
```

Comment: Empty traits, like empty interfaces, can serve as Sentinels or Unifying types.

Comment: could you please show some link/doc about "Sentinels or Unifying types" and their benefit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Building on @user2864740

A simple example. (This is just one use-case)

Let's define a data structure for simple expressions. We want numbers to exist and a plus which combines expressions.

```
trait Expression

case class Number(i: Int) extends Expression
case class Plus(e1: Expression, e2: Expression) extends Expression
```

Now in order to evaluate an `Expression`, we define a method like this.

```
def evaluate(e: Expression): Int = e match {
  case Number(i) => i
  case Plus(e1, e2) => evaluate(e1) + evaluate(e2)
}
```

Since we have `Expression` as a parameter for `Plus`, we can put `Plus` or `Number` inside it.

```
val myExpression = Plus(Plus(Number(1),Number(2)), Number(4))
evaluate(myExpression) //yields 7
```

We just used the empty trait as a common super type (a connection) for `Number` and `Plus`, enabling us to pattern-match for `evaluate` and use `Plus` inside `Plus`.
I hope this is not too confusing.

Comment: One benefit is that we could use pattern-match. Any other benefit?

Comment: That and you have a common supertype that is not something like `Any` or `AnyRef`. This is the only reason that I use empty traits. Maybe there is another use-case, but then someone else will have to provide an example.